# How to extract Hashtags from Tweepy using tweepy.Cursor and api.search?

Tags: python-2.7, twitter, hashtag, tweepy

Tweepy has done a good job extracting all other information (except hashtags) I need by applying the tweepy.Cursor and api.search methods (as shown below). I know from the documentation that Hashtags are under this structure Status > entities > hashtags. And I tried to locate (below) the "hashtags" directory within the methods but to no avail:

```
print "tweet", dir(tweet)
print "////////////////"
print "tweet._api", dir(tweet._api)
print "////////////////"
print "tweet.text", dir(tweet.text)
print "////////////////"
print "tweet.entities", dir(tweet.entities)
print "////////////////"
print "tweet.author", dir(tweet.author)
print "////////////////"
print "tweet.user", dir(tweet.user)
```

My code is here:

```
import tweepy

ckey = ""
csecret = ""
atoken = ""
asecret = ""

OAUTH_KEYS = {'consumer_key':ckey, 'consumer_secret':csecret,
    'access_token_key':atoken, 'access_token_secret':asecret}
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(OAUTH_KEYS['consumer_key'], OAUTH_KEYS['consumer_secret'])
api = tweepy.API(auth)

for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q=('"good book"'), since='2014-09-16', until='2014-09-17').items(5):

    print "Name:", tweet.author.name.encode('utf8')
    print "Screen-name:", tweet.author.screen_name.encode('utf8')
    print "Tweet created:", tweet.created_at
    print "Tweet:", tweet.text.encode('utf8')
    print "Retweeted:", tweet.retweeted
    print "Favourited:", tweet.favorited
    print "Location:", tweet.user.location.encode('utf8')
    print "Time-zone:", tweet.user.time_zone
    print "Geo:", tweet.geo
    print "//////////////////"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Get the [`hashtags`](https://dev.twitter.com/overview/api/entities-in-twitter-objects#hashtags) from the [`entities` dictionary](https://dev.twitter.com/overview/api/entities-in-twitter-objects):

```
print tweet.entities.get('hashtags')
```

Comment: I get empty results, has anything changed with the API?

Answer (score 4):

Don't have the rep to comment but to answer Fabian Bosler's question - since entities is a dictionary, try

```
tweet.entities['hashtags']
```

That worked for me.